# Excel 2010 - want to multiply numbers without typing excessively

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a column B, so my data is from B1 to say B500.
I want C1 to be B1

C2 to be B1*B2.

C3 to be B1*B2*B3

C4 to be B1*...*B4
...

C500 to be B1*...*B500

Is there an easier way to do this rather than typing the formula manually?
I think I can use the function PRODUCT, but I would still have to type the rest of the references manually. Anyone has a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `PRODUCT()` function, passing a range of cells as an argument. Simply enter the following into `C1`:

```
=PRODUCT(B$1:B1)
```

Then drag the formula down (by grabbing the small square at the bottom right of the cell highlight rectangle).

The `$` means an absolute address, so the start of the range remains at `B1` while the end is extended for each new row that you drag the formula to - for `C2` it'll become `B$1:B2`, for `C3` it'll become `B$1:B3`, and so on.

---

Alternatively, if the numbers in B1-B500 are sequential from 1 to 500, you can use the `FACT()` function (which calculates the [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) of a given number) to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I do this sort of thing:

- In C1, I set `=B1`
- In C2, I set `=B2*C1`
- In C3 through C500, I make it a copy of C2, by selecting a box and using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

When Excel copies formulas, it uses relative addressing, unless you tell it not to.

So C500 ends up with a formula that says `=B500*C499`.